# In R how do you create a column with unique values based on time and date values in multiple columns

Tags: r, unique, data-manipulation

I have a data frame with two columns, see below:

```
Date        Time  
2020-01-12  00:00:01  
2020-01-12  00:00:02  
2020-01-12  00:01:01  
2020-01-12  00:01:02  
2020-01-12  00:02:01  
2020-01-12  00:02:02  
2020-01-12  00:10:01  
2020-01-12  00:10:02  
2020-01-12  00:11:01  
2020-01-12  00:11:02  
2020-01-12  00:12:01  
2020-01-12  00:12:02  
2020-01-12  00:20:01  
2020-01-12  00:20:02  
2020-01-12  00:21:01  
2020-01-12  00:21:02  
2020-01-12  00:22:01  
2020-01-12  00:22:02        
2020-01-13  00:00:01  
2020-01-13  00:00:02  
2020-01-13  00:01:01  
2020-01-13  00:01:02  
2020-01-13  00:02:01  
2020-01-13  00:02:02  
2020-01-13  00:10:01  
2020-01-13  00:10:02  
2020-01-13  00:11:01  
2020-01-13  00:11:02  
2020-01-13  00:12:01  
2020-01-13  00:12:02  
2020-01-13  00:20:01  
2020-01-13  00:20:02  
2020-01-13  00:21:01  
2020-01-13  00:21:02  
2020-01-13  00:22:01  
2020-01-13  00:22:02
```

I want to create a third column with unique values starting at 1 and going to x, based on values in the first two columns. Specifically, I want to focus on the minutes place in the second column first and then the day place in the first column second, so that the results looks like below:

```
Date        Time      Value  
2020-01-12  00:00:01  1  
2020-01-12  00:00:02  1  
2020-01-12  00:01:01  1  
2020-01-12  00:01:02  1  
2020-01-12  00:02:01  1  
2020-01-12  00:02:02  1  
2020-01-12  00:10:01  2  
2020-01-12  00:10:02  2  
2020-01-12  00:11:01  2  
2020-01-12  00:11:02  2  
2020-01-12  00:12:01  2  
2020-01-12  00:12:02  2  
2020-01-12  00:20:01  3  
2020-01-12  00:20:02  3  
2020-01-12  00:21:01  3  
2020-01-12  00:21:02  3  
2020-01-12  00:22:01  3  
2020-01-12  00:22:02  3        
2020-01-13  00:00:01  4  
2020-01-13  00:00:02  4  
2020-01-13  00:01:01  4  
2020-01-13  00:01:02  4  
2020-01-13  00:02:01  4  
2020-01-13  00:02:02  4  
2020-01-13  00:10:01  5  
2020-01-13  00:10:02  5  
2020-01-13  00:11:01  5  
2020-01-13  00:11:02  5  
2020-01-13  00:12:01  5  
2020-01-13  00:12:02  5  
2020-01-13  00:20:01  6  
2020-01-13  00:20:02  6  
2020-01-13  00:21:01  6  
2020-01-13  00:21:02  6  
2020-01-13  00:22:01  6  
2020-01-13  00:22:02  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
transform(df, Value = cumsum(c(1, diff(as.POSIXlt(paste(Date, Time)))>60)))

         Date     Time Value
1  2020-01-12 00:00:01     1
2  2020-01-12 00:00:02     1
3  2020-01-12 00:01:01     1
4  2020-01-12 00:01:02     1
5  2020-01-12 00:02:01     1
6  2020-01-12 00:02:02     1
7  2020-01-12 00:10:01     2
8  2020-01-12 00:10:02     2
9  2020-01-12 00:11:01     2
10 2020-01-12 00:11:02     2
11 2020-01-12 00:12:01     2
12 2020-01-12 00:12:02     2
13 2020-01-12 00:20:01     3
14 2020-01-12 00:20:02     3
15 2020-01-12 00:21:01     3
16 2020-01-12 00:21:02     3
17 2020-01-12 00:22:01     3
18 2020-01-12 00:22:02     3
19 2020-01-13 00:00:01     4
20 2020-01-13 00:00:02     4
21 2020-01-13 00:01:01     4
22 2020-01-13 00:01:02     4
23 2020-01-13 00:02:01     4
24 2020-01-13 00:02:02     4
25 2020-01-13 00:10:01     5
26 2020-01-13 00:10:02     5
27 2020-01-13 00:11:01     5
28 2020-01-13 00:11:02     5
29 2020-01-13 00:12:01     5
30 2020-01-13 00:12:02     5
31 2020-01-13 00:20:01     6
32 2020-01-13 00:20:02     6
33 2020-01-13 00:21:01     6
34 2020-01-13 00:21:02     6
35 2020-01-13 00:22:01     6
36 2020-01-13 00:22:02     6
```

Comment: This works simply and perfectly. Can you take a moment to walk me through how it operates? Thank you.

Comment: @Jacob first it creates a POXISlt object which is literaly just a time object. Then it looks at the difference between the current time and the previous time. and you just do a cummulative sum of that and add 1 to it

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation. I greatly appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% mutate(Hour = substr(Time, 4,4), Value = rleid(Hour)) %>% select(-Hour)
         Date     Time Value
1  2020-01-12 00:00:01     1
2  2020-01-12 00:00:02     1
3  2020-01-12 00:01:01     1
4  2020-01-12 00:01:02     1
5  2020-01-12 00:02:01     1
6  2020-01-12 00:02:02     1
7  2020-01-12 00:10:01     2
8  2020-01-12 00:10:02     2
9  2020-01-12 00:11:01     2
10 2020-01-12 00:11:02     2
11 2020-01-12 00:12:01     2
12 2020-01-12 00:12:02     2
13 2020-01-12 00:20:01     3
14 2020-01-12 00:20:02     3
15 2020-01-12 00:21:01     3
16 2020-01-12 00:21:02     3
17 2020-01-12 00:22:01     3
18 2020-01-12 00:22:02     3
19 2020-01-13 00:00:01     4
20 2020-01-13 00:00:02     4
21 2020-01-13 00:01:01     4
22 2020-01-13 00:01:02     4
23 2020-01-13 00:02:01     4
24 2020-01-13 00:02:02     4
25 2020-01-13 00:10:01     5
26 2020-01-13 00:10:02     5
27 2020-01-13 00:11:01     5
28 2020-01-13 00:11:02     5
29 2020-01-13 00:12:01     5
30 2020-01-13 00:12:02     5
31 2020-01-13 00:20:01     6
32 2020-01-13 00:20:02     6
33 2020-01-13 00:21:01     6
34 2020-01-13 00:21:02     6
35 2020-01-13 00:22:01     6
36 2020-01-13 00:22:02     6
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it doesn't work. It maintains the same value throughout.